# query not work for single quote apostrophe

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

`phpmyadmin` query not work for single quote / apostrophe.

Not Work

```
ALTER TABLE 'about_team' CHANGE 'position' 'pp' INT( 11 ) NOT NULL
```

Work:

```
ALTER TABLE `about_team` CHANGE `position` `pp` INT( 11 ) NOT NULL
```

Same query but not work, gives error:

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near **''about_team' CHANGE 'position' 'pp' INT(11) NOT NULL'** at line 1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

it is because when you using `single` quote, it just means it is a `STRING`. Whereas `BACTICK` (*the second query*) means escaping a column.

> ```
> 'about_team' is not equal with `about_team`
>
> 'about_team' is STRING
> `about_team` is a Table Name
> ```

Actually backticks enclosing the names are *optional* since the names used where not on  `MySQL Reserved Keyword List`.

- [MySQL Reserved Keywords](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html)

Usually, *`single quotes` are used around values* while *`backticks` are for table names and column names*.